# Is there a way to adjust the memory allocation to increase the allocation for apps?

Tags: storage, insufficient-memory

I have an Mi Traveler Android model 10R2 tablet and I am continuously getting a "memory low" message. I have added a SD card and moved some apps to the card, but still get the same messages. In checking the storage area, it shows the allocation of memory as follows:

- Total space 3.09GB
- Apps 84.95MB
- Downloads 116MB
- Misc. 19.16MB
- Available 2.87GB

Then under Apps, it shows the following:

- Total space 252MB
- Apps 204MB
- Available 21.94MB

Is there a way to adjust the memory allocation to increase the allocation for apps?

It seems that I am only getting the low memory when apps are updating or new apps are being downloaded.

Comment: I don't know your tablet model. Does it feature an internal as well as an external SDCard? If so, can you please check how much space is free in "device internal" memory (as opposed to the "internal SD")? This is what causes that error in most cases, as soon as free space drops below ~25MB.

Answer (score 1):

as it stands your internal memory is unable to increase. Adding a SD card will **only** increase space for music, pictures and some apps. 
My assumptions are that your phone is a lower end affordable device. These are plagued with smaller memory, that are almost always maxed out right out of the box. Your solutions are limited to your device and the applications you install.

One solution would be to move as many apps to your SD card as possible. The problem lies with many apps not supporting this feature.

Second solution would be to run only the apps your phone came with and not update them. Of course this is not what a user would want, and is not recommended.

The last option would be to buy a new phone with internal space of at least 4GB to not run into this trouble, of course the more internal space the better. 
Also note that alot of apps use more space because higher end phones have the ability to have them installed. This leaves lower end phones in trouble because they can no longer run the apps they use to. 
Sorry to be bearer of bad news, I hope this information was of help.

Answer (score 0):

The listed amounts are for the internal memory.

Comment: Would you know the answer to this: Is there a way to adjust the memory allocation to increase the allocation for apps?

Comment: You can't add more internal memory to the tablet, if that's what you mean.  Move some more apps to the SD card so that they don't take up space in the internal memory.